# Run future Rails migrations after db:schema:load

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I feel like this must be a question that has been answered in the past but I could not find anything with Google.

According to the Rails guides:

> There is no need (and it is error prone) to deploy a new instance of an app by replaying the entire migration history. It is much simpler and faster to just load into the database a description of the current schema.

However, when you load the database via the schema file there would be no data in the `schema_migrations` table and therefore any migrations that are added to the project in the future cannot be run without first running the entire migration history.

Am I missing something here? If I create a new instance of the Rails DB from a schema file how can I run any future migrations against it?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb#L214 is the schema load code, and it contains no special handling of schema_migrations.  I would ignore the guide and use migrations.  If your migrations are broken, that's a problem.

Comment: If you've deployed your app once. Then just running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` on your next deployment should update your db schema to the latest.

Comment: @JimVanFleet If you are running all of your migrations and any migration references a table that was created in a previous migration, won't the migrations fail?

Comment: @PhilCowan Short answer: no.  What you are describing is a very common occurrence in migrations-- adding a column to an existing table is a reference migration use case.  

When a migration is created, that is why the timestamp is added to the filename, to provide an easily visible ordering for the migrations in which to run.  Each migration is processed in turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is preferred to set up a new database with a schema load rather than running old migrations, and it should be expected that the schema_migrations table is updated correctly when running a `rake db:schema:load`. When you run `rake db:schema:load` the schema_migrations table should be populated based on the value of the `version` key-pair passed to the `::define` method in the db/schema.rb file.

For example:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161208214643) do
end
```

should update the schema_migrations table up to the migration listed in version. The version value should be populated in the db/schema.rb file automatically after running a `rake db:schema:dump` or `rake db:migrate` (which invokes db:schema:dump). This allows for any future migrations to be run normally, as should be expected.

The inserts into the schema_migrations table are handled by the `assume_migrated_upto_version` method, as seen in the following files:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema.rb#L52
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L1021